# How to remove duplicates within a string from the table in SQL server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I got a table which contains a column of strings. Those strings are separated by a `;`. Now I want to remove the duplicates after the string is splitted. For example:

```
-----------
| w;w;e;e |
-----------
| q;r;r;q |
-----------
| b;n;n;b |
-----------
```

The result should be:

```
-------
| w;e |
-------
| q;r |
-------
| b;n |
-------
```

Also it should not be a `Select` function but a (not 100% sure) `delete` function. So the values in the original table won't be duplicated anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an `update` statement, this will de-duplicate your column:

```
update t 
  set col = stuff((
    select distinct
      ';'+s.Value
    from string_split(t.col,';') as s
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(1024)')
    ,1,1,'');
```

---

In sql server 2016, you can use [**`string_split()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) along with the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) to concatenate only distinct values.

```
select 
    t.id
  , t.col
  , dedup = stuff((
    select distinct
      ';'+s.Value
    from string_split(t.col,';') as s
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(1024)')
    ,1,1,'')
from t
```

dbfiddle demo: [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=013b46793fa1238d806f780e9acf86fe)

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MAME55141; this demo uses a CSV Splitter function by Jeff Moden in the absence of `string_split()`.

returns:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id |   col   | dedup |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | w;w;e;e | e;w   |
|  2 | q;r;r;q | q;r   |
|  3 | b;n;n;b | b;n   |
+----+---------+-------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Comment: Hello SqlZim, thanks for this answer. Tho it just selects the column, but it doenst seem to remove the duplicates from my table, am I right? Or should I use the new `dedup` column for my table and remove the old one? Because the new dedup column is not saved in my table?

Comment: @wouterdejong Updated the answer with an example of an `update` statement to get the deduplicated value for `col`.

Answer (score 0):

If "e", "r", and "w" are the only values in the string, then the simplest way is to reconstruct the string:

```
select stuff( (case when string like '%e%' then ';e' else '' end) +
              (case when string like '%r%' then ';r' else '' end) +
              (case when string like '%w%' then ';w' else '' end),
              1, 1, ''
            )
```

I suspect the values might be limited, because these look like file permissions (read/write/execute).  Otherwise, you will need to parse the string into separate rows (using XML, a UDF, or a recursive CTE) and recombine the values.

You should learn a lesson here.  Don't store lists in strings.  These values should either be flags (if I am right about there only being a handful of values).  Or, they should be on separate rows of a another table.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thank you for your answer. In my case the only valyes are not just `e`, `r` or `w`. Those are just some `strings` which I used to make the example easier to understand. I changed the example a bit to make it more clear.